# How to retain (per session/tab) the uploaded file in server (Nodejs/Java script backend)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

My requirement - Single page application having a File upload and many other sliders/dropdowns that fire events to server whenever there is a change.

Ideal workflow for my application is 
1) User uploads file using File Upload widget-> server should retain this file and use this for further requests from the same client
2) User changes sliders or dropdown values -> Client fires requests to the server. Server makes use of the file that was uploaded initially and applies some logic and returns a response that is rendered somewhere on the page.

User can simultaneously open the app in multiple tabs on web browser and each tab should be isolated, i.e., user can upload different files in different tabs and server should retain files and respond respectively.

Please let me know what technologies/frameworks are best fit for my use case. 
Any links/example pages having the similar use case would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this short of scheme:

1. When you upload the file, the server stores the file somewhere, coins a unique ID for that file and then stores that unique ID such that it can associate that unique ID with the recently uploaded file - probably using a simple database to associate the two in a persistent manner.
2. The unique ID is then returned to the client after the upload. The client window then keeps track of that unique ID in a javascript variable for that window.
3. Whenever that window wishes to apply some operation to that file, it sends an Ajax request to the server with the file's unique ID and parameters for the operation.  For example, an ajax request to crop a file like this: http://x.com/api/crop?fileID=19482302&x=0&y=0&h=1024&w=2048.
4. When the server receives the Ajax request, it uses the unique ID to find which file it is associated with, applies the operation and returns the results.
5. The client receives the results and renders whatever it needs to render to show the results.
6. To keep unused files from building up on the server, the server probably needs to "age" away files that are no longer in use.  For this, you can create some sort of expiration.  When a file is accessed, it's recent access time is recorded.  Then, you can have some periodic timer (say every hour) that cycles through the files and remove any who haven't been accessed recently (say in the last day or 6 hours or whatever time is appropriate for your app).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you think websockets can be of any help in this case? If so, please elaborate on using websockets for this.

Comment: @Techenthusiast - From what you've described, I don't see any particular reason to use webSockets for this.  The scheme I've outlined would work perfectly fine with ajax calls and does not require webSockets.   webSockets are required when you want to send real-time data from server to client when it occurs, not as a response to a client request.  You have not described that as a requirement here.

Comment: @Techenthusiast -   The scheme could be made to work with webSockets where each server side webSocket was associated when an uploaded file and any requests on that webSocket would be applied to that associated file.  But, I don't personally see any reason to do it that way rather than just use Ajax requests as my answer describes.